# Обработать данные документа Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Уже всю голову сломал. Опыта работы с JavaScript мало, поэтому буду благодарен за помощь.

Простая функция возвращает данные из базы MongoDB в виде массива документов Mongoose

```
return model.find ({}, (err, result) => {
    mongoose.disconnect();
    if(err) throw new Error(err);

    console.log(result[0]);
    return result;
});
```

Для теста я ловлю первый результат массива и пытаюсь из него получить данные. На этом уровне всё прекрасно, я получаю:

```
{
  _id: 5ec274ad476b362bc4eeb5f1,
  firstName: 'test',
  secondName: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  login: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  __v: 0
}
```

Теперь легко и понятно, что можно получить конкретное значением, например, поля firstName, вызвав:

```
result[0].firstName
```

Но при попытке перебора всех свойств, вдруг начинаются чудеса. Например, пытаюсь получить в виде ключ/значение:

```
const entries = Object.entries(result[0]);
        entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
        })
```

В ответ мне выдаётся:

```
$__: [object Object]
isNew: false
errors: undefined
_doc: [object Object]
$locals: [object Object]
$op: null
$init: true
```

И я понимаю, что документ представляет собой захумудрённый объект, к которому на жигулях не подъедешь.

Я уже кучу подходов перепробовал, как из документации mongoose, так и из примеров в интернете. У меня никак не получается получить простой массив объектов с полями ключ/значение.

Comment: Давно не пользовался монгой, но там вроде documents объект возвращается, у которого можно метод `toArray` вызвать `result.toArray()`